# Error while using Heroku commands on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, heroku

I have installed Heroku on my Ubuntu 16.0.4 from this link.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#debian-ubuntu

But when I ran the heroku --version from my terminal then I get this error.

```
WARNING
WARNING Node version must be >=7.10.0 to use the Heroku CLI
WARNING
/home/nikhil/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/heroku-
cli/node_modules/cli-engine/lib/cli.js:73
  async run() {
        ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> 
(/home/nikhil/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/heroku-
cli/bin/run.js:10:34)
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: update `node`. Note the second line, you need `node` version >= `7.0`

Comment: But when i ran the heroku --version command on MacOx with the same node version then it runs perfectly fine. The only difference is here i downloaded the heroku via the commands and on Mac i had an installer for heroku.

Comment: a possible explanation for it would be that when you are insatlling it on MacOS, `homebrew` takes care of the dependencies, but on Ubuntu/Debian, you're going to need to update `node` to the required version. I would suggest you update your version of `node` first (using `npm` or `n`) to `>=7.0` and checking if it works :)

Comment: Thanks bud I will try this.

Comment: Thanks man after updating my node to the latest version heroku starts running fine.